# Can you add a Modal dialog to an existing component in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, dialog, modal-dialog, mat-dialog

I have a mat-card element with an image inside.

**HTML**

```
<mat-card id="CARDBOX">
       <img class="logo" src="path/image.jpg" alt="image" height=25px/>
</mat-card>
```

**TS**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cardbox',
  templateUrl: './cardbox.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cardbox.component.scss']
})
export class CardboxComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

}
```

I want it so that by clicking on the image it will open up a Mat Dialog with some more information about the image. Is it possible to do this by adding to my existing Cardbox component? I understand that I need an openDialog() method but I am unsure how to implement that into the existing ts component.

Answer (score 2):

Its simple just add click event
HTML

```
<mat-card id="CARDBOX" (click)="openDialog()">
   <img class="logo" src="path/image.jpg" alt="image" height=25px/>
</mat-card>
```

TS

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cardbox',
  templateUrl: './cardbox.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cardbox.component.scss']
})
export class CardboxComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  openDialog() {
   this.dialog.open(CardBoxComponent);
  }
}
```

You may experience issues with this in future I recommand to use another component for this for ex. CardBoxDialog. and then on this componet in HTML template just add

```
<app-cardbox></app-cardbox>
```

Comment: When I added this to my existing Cardbox component, nothing on the screen rendered anymore. Do I have to make a separate class with a different constructor?

Comment: Adding (private dialog: MatDialog) to my existing constructor completely got rid of everything when the code is run.

Comment: What version of angular are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Angular 10